# Extract weight and price values from strings using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the follow strings. I would like three regex expressions that for each string extracts the weight, unit of measurement, and the first price. They need to be generalisable to other strings of the same form.
`'250g - £3.55£12.3 per kg'` extract "250", "g", and "3.55"
`'500g - £7.15£14.8 per kg'` extract "500", "g", and "7.15"
`'2kg - £14.85£20.98 per kg'` extract "2", "kg", and "14.85"

Comment: please show your attempt it cannot be that hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regular expression should extract the three values you need:

```
/(\d+)(k?g) - £([^£]+)/
```

See https://regex101.com/r/A7npHN/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
const regex = /(\d+)(g|kg)\s*-\s*£(\d+.\d+)/gm;
const str = `250g - £3.55£12.3 per kg
500g - £7.15£14.8 per kg
2kg - £14.85£20.98 per kg`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression.

```
^(?<wt>\d+)(?<wt_unit>\S+)\s+-\D+(?<price>\d+\.\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B3Zp2G/1/)

Javascript's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                  match beginning of line
(?<wt>\d+)         match 1+ digits in cap grp 'wt'
(?<wt_unit>\S+)    match 1+ chars other than w'space in cap grp 'wt_unit'
\s+-\D+            match 1+ w'space chars, '-', 1+ chars other than digits
(?<price>\d+\.\d+) match 1+ digits, '.', 1+ digits in cap grp 'price'
```